# Loading Images From A URL(nsurlconnection)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, nsurlconnection

I have to Implement a UITableView that should display all hosted photos. Load the photos synchronously and asynchronously in different tabs.
how to call images from url??

Comment: wOw..how come it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load an image from a url:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

You can use GCD to perform the actions asynchronously. There's a good tutorial of almost exactly what you're trying to achieve [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)

Comment: ya but i have to load multiple images in from url which should be display into my tableview. what should be code for this. actually i am new in learning and i have created a table .what should be next

Answer (score 0):

You can used the Apple TableView Lazy Loading. They have sample codes that download images asynchonously to avoid freeze of UI. See link below

[Apple LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)